# How to get Paperclip image URL through GraphQL Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, paperclip, graphql-ruby

I'm trying to make the Item's Paperclip thumbnail variant available through the [GraphQL Ruby gem](https://graphql-ruby.org):

`app/graphql/types/item_type.rb`:

```
class Types::ItemType < Types::BaseObject
  description 'An item'
  field :title, String, null: false
  field :thumbnail_image, String, null: true

  def thumbnail_image
    item.image.url(:thumb_2x)
  end
end
```

This just results in the following error:

```
"message": "undefined local variable or method `item' for #<Types::ItemType:0x00007ff3f1dbc4e0>"
```

What's the right way to get this to work? Do I need a resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I needed to do this:

```
def thumbnail_image
  object.image.url(:thumb_2x)
end
```